# How to write text below the container in row

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have always struggled with making this ui dynamically. Its a row of 4 or can be more than 4 containers with images in it and below that row there is text showing the name of the category made. I currently doing the name part with padding's according to my own device but it slips away in larger or smaller screen size devices other than mine. How can I tackle this. [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KawdV.jpg) is also attached for better understanding if required. Also in the next code named intopage I am trying to stick the please read lines and the terms and conditions, privacy policy to the bottom but it isn't sticking

```
Row(          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      height: 80,
                      width: 80,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          border: Border.all(color: Colors.black),
                          borderRadius:
                              const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))),
                      child: Center(
                        child: Image.asset("assets/salonicon.png",
                            scale: 1.2, color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: 80,
                      width: 80,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          border: Border.all(color: Colors.black),
                          borderRadius:
                              const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))),
                      child: Center(
                        child: Image.asset("assets/hairdresser.png",
                            scale: 1.2, color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: 80,
                      width: 80,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          border: Border.all(color: Colors.black),
                          borderRadius:
                              const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))),
                      child: Center(
                        child: Image.asset("assets/facial-massage.png",
                            scale: 1.2, color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: 80,
                      width: 80,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          border: Border.all(color: Colors.black),
                          borderRadius:
                              const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))),
                      child: Center(
                        child: Image.asset("assets/body-massage.png",
                            scale: 1.2, color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 10),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  // crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30.0),
                      child: Text(
                        "Salons".toUpperCase(),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 50.0),
                      child: Text(
                        "Hair".toUpperCase(),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 60.0),
                      child: Text(
                        "Skin".toUpperCase(),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 65.0),
                      child: Text(
                        "Body".toUpperCase(),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),




class IntroPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const IntroPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFF29F76),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Image.asset(
                  "assets/intropage.png",
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    top: 550,
                  ),
                  child: Center(
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => const SignUpPage()));
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        width: 180,
                        height: 60,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            border: Border.all(
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                            borderRadius:
                                const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(40))),
                        child: const Center(
                          child: Text(
                            "Sign Up",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 20,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: Colors.black),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    top: 650,
                  ),
                  child: Center(
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => const SignInPage()));
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        width: 180,
                        height: 60,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            border: Border.all(
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                            borderRadius:
                                const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(40))),
                        child: const Center(
                          child: Text(
                            "Sign In",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 20,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: Color(0xFFFE6B01)),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    top: 750,
                  ),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        height: 2,
                        width: 150,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      const Text(
                        "  Please Read  ",
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        height: 2,
                        width: 150,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    top: 760,
                  ),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, top: 6),
                        child: GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () {
                            Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) =>
                                        TermsandConditions()));
                          },
                          child: const Text(
                            "Terms & Conditions",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                decoration: TextDecoration.underline),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 20, top: 6),
                        child: GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () {
                            Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) => PrivacyPolicy()));
                          },
                          child: const Text(
                            "Privacy Policy",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                decoration: TextDecoration.underline),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use row then columns to specify them according to your needs it took me 3 minutes to change your code according to your needs super easy just practice a couple of times and you won' forget it.

```
   Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      children: <Widget>[
        Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              height: 100.0,
              width: 100.0,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  image: const DecorationImage(
                    image: AssetImage('assets/rnpic.png'),
                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                  ),
                  border: Border.all(color: Colors.black),
                  borderRadius:
                      const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))),
              child: Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(),
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                      child: Container(
                        width: 70,
                        height: 30,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: const Color(0xFFFF6D00),
                            border: Border.all(
                                color: const Color(0xFFFF6D00)),
                            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                              topRight: Radius.circular(20.0),
                            )),
                        child: const Center(
                          child: Text(
                            "-50% OFF",
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          width: 150,
          child: Center(
            child: Text(
              "Colorado Salon special hairstyle",
              style:
                  TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, fontSize: 16),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          width: 80,
          height: 30,
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              color: Color(0xFFFF6D00),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))),
          child: Center(
            child: Text(
              "View".toUpperCase(),
              style: const TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600, color: Colors.white),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    )
  ],
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the layout like this

```
Row(
mainAxisAlignment : MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
  children:[
   //item 1
    Column(
      children:[
        Icon(),
        Text(),
      ]
     ),
    //item 2
    Column(
      children:[
        Icon(),
        Text(),
      ]
     ),
    //item 3
    Column(
      children:[
        Icon(),
        Text(),
      ]
     )
   ]
)
```

Comment: It worked perfect thank you so much. One more request can you guide me through another mistake I'm doing. I've updated the code about that in the question please let me know about it the  Please read and the content under it needs to be fixed at bottom but in my case it goes high in larger screen sizes.